# all validator messages in JSF are displayed 

Tags: regex, validation, jsf-2

i am getting all the validate messages displayed at once when i use to enter a value in 1 field it shows validation messages of all the other fields too.
i have applied validation on all the fields in the following manner:

```
<td>User Name</td>
                            <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtName" styleClass="text-box" value="#{UserSearch.Name}" validatorMessage="Please enter a valid name." maxlength="75">
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="^([A-Za-z])*$" />
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:message for="txtName" styleClass="Error" />
```

can anyone help what is the basic problem behind. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  (For the other fields.  Are they sharing an id?  If so, that would be the problem.)

Comment: no they are not sharing same id, i have specified unique property for each of them. ' <td>Email</td>
                              <td><h:inputText id="txtEmail" value="#{input.email}" styleClass="text-box" validatorMessage="Please enter a valid email address.">
                               <f:validateRegex pattern="^[\w-]+@[\w-]+\.(com|net|org|edu|mil)$"></f:validateRegex>   
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:message for="txtEmail" styleClass="Error"></h:message> '

Comment: Are all validation mesasges displayed for each field or just once? If once -is it at the bottom?

Comment: it displayed for each field, and if enter a invalid name submit it, it just start showing error message for all the other fields in the form, and i haven't put require attribute 'true' for any filed.

Comment: @BalusC SSCCE? in fat whenever i refresh my page all the errors are dipslayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for is connected with partial submit of form which could be done with ajax.

Myself I am using primefaces which help a lot with ajax and my registration form looks like this:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg.email}" for="email" />                    
                            <p:inputText id="email" value="#{registrationBean.email}" required="true" validatorMessage="#{msg.wrong_email}" requiredMessage="#{msg.email_required}" >
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                                <p:ajax partialSubmit="@this" update="messages" />
                            </p:inputText>
```

Comment: @atias thanx. i have tried this primefaces partialsubmit too but the problem is the same, when i use to refresh the page or try to navigate to next page it displays validator messages for all the other fields too. :(

Comment: Could you please paste whole code to the topic, because I am not sure if I understand it correctly.

Comment: it would be difficult to paste whole code because it is quiet big.